# Flutter, local SQLite database and Role based access control

Tags: flutter, sqlite, roles, flutter-desktop, role-base-authorization

I am new in Flutter and still learn basics and my next step is to create user role-based authorization Flutter desktop app using local database (SQLite).
In the web I can't find any resources about this approach. Most of them is about Firebase auth.

For example I would like to display widgets based on user role or have admin panel to manage and assign roles to the users.

I suppose that i need at least 3 tables (Users, Roles, User-Roles) with many-to-many relationship.

Can someone lead me to the appropriate resoures or give a hint where should I start?

Any idea, hint or link to the source will be valuable to me.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1732/database-model-with-users-roles-and-rights

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is one of the simplest forms of SQL that you can find hence it's one of the default choices not only for front-end Sdks such as Flutter but also for backend such as Django.

[I have created this very detailed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEUo98kqRzs) that explains how you can integrate with SQLite using the SQFlite plugin in Flutter for creating a CRUD application.

SQLite doesn't have built-in user management so you need to start creating user tables and manage those relationships manually.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, of course this is valuable video but not cover user roles or auth. btw Im already your subscriber since I dived in Flutter :) Keep good work on.